# How do I freeze a pandas dataframe column when subsetting the data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I created a new column in a dataframe that divides one column by the another. I then subsetted the dataframe. For some reason, the calculations in the subsetted dataframe for the newly created column are different than in the original dataframe. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import DataFrame, Series 

with open('mc2016_all.txt','r') as file_in: #reading item.csv file into Python
    mc_subgroups = pd.read_table(file_in, delimiter = ',', header=0)

list(mc_subgroups.columns.values)

mc_subgroups['Percentage of Students'] = (mc_subgroups['Students Tested'])/(mc_subgroups['Total Tested At Entity Level'])

mc_math_EL= mc_subgroups[(mc_subgroups['Test Id']==2) & (mc_subgroups['Subgroup ID']==160) & (mc_subgroups['Grade']==13)]

mc_math_EL['Percentage Met']= pd.to_numeric(mc_math_EL['Percentage Standard Met'], errors='coerce')

mc_math_EL['Percentage Exceeded']= pd.to_numeric(mc_math_EL['Percentage Standard Exceeded'], errors='coerce')

mc_math_EL['Both Met and Exceeded'] = mc_math_EL['Percentage Exceeded'] + mc_math_EL['Percentage Met']

mc_math_EL1= mc_math_EL.sort_values(by='Both Met and Exceeded', ascending=False, na_position='last')

mc_math_EL2 = mc_math_EL1[['County Code','District Code', 'School Code','Subgroup ID','Total Tested At Entity Level','Grade','Test Id','Students Tested','Percentage Standard Exceeded', 'Percentage Standard Met', 'Both Met and Exceeded', 'Percentage of Students']].copy()

mc_math_EL2.to_csv("mc_math_EL.csv")
```

The output for the `mc_subgroups['Percentage of Students']` column looks like this:

```
Out[13]: 
0        0.152082
1        0.151848
2        0.155345
3        0.155647
4        0.151159
5        0.150873
6        0.144203
7        0.144004
8        0.139117
9        0.139206
10       0.137732
11       0.137746
```

But the outcome for the `mc_math_EL2['Percentage of Students']` results in all `1.0`:

```
Out[14]: 
23314    1.0
22365    1.0
23606    1.0
1907     1.0
17751    1.0
8110     1.0
35354    1.0
8651     1.0
10042    1.0
9747     1.0
```

Is there any way to freeze the `'Percentage of Students'` column from the first dataframe so that the percentages come through in the `mc_math_EL2` dataframe.

Comment: You do realize that the indexes in your `Out[13]` and `Out[14]` differ significantly. Probably, the ratio for the indexes in `Out[14]` are 1.0. In fact, they most certainly are, because the values will not change unless something explicitly changes them.

Comment: I did realize that about the indices. I guess you are right that the value doesn't change. So I must be doing something else wrong because it should be a percentage.

Comment: If the ratio is 1.0, it means it is 100%...

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant it should be a smaller ratio. When I open it as a CSV file, it is 1.0 as well. I have to create a new column a different way.